# Oracle Plus (+) Joins to ANSI conversion

Tags: oracle, outer-join, ansi-sql

I'm in the middle of a warehouse migration from Oracle to SQL Datawarehouse Azure and ran into an issue with this query.

The original query from Oracle - it returns `1872520` rows.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 STG_REV_APPORTION_CSC_NO t1,
 STG_SEP_VL t2,
 STG_SEP_VL t3
WHERE
 t3.BUSINESS_DATE(+)    = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
AND t3.CSC_APP_NO(+)     = t1.CSC_APP_NO
AND t3.JOURNEY_NO(+)     = t1.JOURNEY_NO
AND t3.PURSE_TXN_CTR(+)  = t1.PURSE_TXN_CTR
AND t2.BUSINESS_DATE(+) = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
AND t2.CSC_APP_NO(+)    = t1.CSC_APP_NO
AND t2.JOURNEY_NO(+)    = t1.JOURNEY_NO
AND
 (
   t2.TRIP_NO(+) + 1
 )
 = t1.TRIP_NO
AND
 (
   t2.MSG_TYPE_CD(+)  = 13070
 AND t3.MSG_TYPE_CD(+) = 4357
 );
```

Taking clues from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm), I tried query re-write to ANSI:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM STG_REV_APPORTION_CSC_NO t1
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN STG_SEP_VL t3 ON t3.BUSINESS_DATE = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
 AND t3.CSC_APP_NO     = t1.CSC_APP_NO
 AND t3.JOURNEY_NO     = t1.JOURNEY_NO
 AND t3.PURSE_TXN_CTR  = t1.PURSE_TXN_CTR
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN STG_SEP_VL t2 ON t2.BUSINESS_DATE = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
AND t2.CSC_APP_NO   = t1.CSC_APP_NO
AND t2.JOURNEY_NO    = t1.JOURNEY_NO 
AND (t2.TRIP_NO + 1)  = t1.TRIP_NO
WHERE t2.MSG_TYPE_CD = 13070 AND t3.MSG_TYPE_CD = 4357
```

It returns zero rows. The ANSI version should work on oracle instance - it returns zero rows there too.

I then tried to convert plus join to ANSI using refactor option on toad. I get the following

```
SELECT *
  FROM STG_SEP_VL  T2
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN STG_REV_APPORTION_CSC_NO T1
           ON     (T2.BUSINESS_DATE = T1.BUSINESS_DATE)
              AND (T2.CSC_APP_NO = T1.CSC_APP_NO)
              AND (T2.JOURNEY_NO = T1.JOURNEY_NO)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN STG_SEP_VL T3
           ON     (T3.PURSE_TXN_CTR = T1.PURSE_TXN_CTR)
              AND (T3.BUSINESS_DATE = T1.BUSINESS_DATE)
              AND (T3.CSC_APP_NO = T1.CSC_APP_NO)
              AND (T3.JOURNEY_NO = T1.JOURNEY_NO)
 WHERE     ( ( (T2.TRIP_NO                                             /*(+)*/
                          ) + 1) = T1.TRIP_NO)
       AND ( ( (T2.MSG_TYPE_CD                                         /*(+)*/
                              ) = 13070) AND ( (T3.MSG_TYPE_CD         /*(+)*/
                                                              ) = 4357));
```

Now this query should run on Oracle and return the same number of rows before I can run it on SQL Server. But it doesn't - it returns zero rows.

I looked at the explain plan for both of these queries. Here is how (+) join plan looks like:
[image]

Here is how ANSI version of this query looks like:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: All `(+)` condition must by written in `ON` clause !. No `WHERE` clause need on this query. `RIGHT JOIN STG_SEP_VL t2 ON ... AND t2.MSG_TYPE_CD = 13070`. OR in `where`: `WHERE (t2.MSG_TYPE_CD = 13070 OR t2.MSG_TYPE_CD IS NULL /*(for rows not existing in t2)*/`

Comment: This is horrible. The guy that wrote the (+) query in the first place should be blamed, sorry if it was you. I don't see where the error is but I would say that your query looks more correct than the Toad refactored one, because the `AND (t2.TRIP_NO + 1)  = t1.TRIP_NO` should be in the ON clause and not the WHERE clause, and this is valid for everything that had a (+). What I would do at your place is to decompose: rewrite the original query to use only one table, then 2, then 3. And convert the query to proper syntax using 1 then 2 then 3 tables and compare results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT *
  FROM stg_rev_apportion_csc_no t1 
  LEFT JOIN stg_sep_vl t3
         ON t1.business_date = t3.business_date AND
            t1.csc_app_no = t3.csc_app_no       AND
            t1.journey_no = t3.journey_no       AND
            t1.purse_txn_ctr = t3.purse_txn_no  AND
            4357 = t3.msg_type_cd
  LEFT JOIN stg_sep_vl t2
         ON t1.business_date = t2.business_date AND
            t1.csc_app_no = t2.csc_app_no       AND
            t1.journey_no = t2.journey_no       AND
            t1.trip_no = t2.trip_no + 1         AND
            13070 = t2.msg_type_cd;
```

Tables t2 and t3 are outer joined to t1, so you either list t1 first and do a left join, or list t2 and t3 first and do a right join.

Comment: Awesome! This query came up with exact number of rows on Oracle. It gave many more results on SQL Server - I will debug that problem now :)

Comment: @RKKuppala - So, to be clear: Mike (in the first Comment to the original question) had the right reason for the discrepancy. The outer join condition `t2.MSG_TYPE_CD(+)  = 13070` from the original query cannot be replaced by "outer join" and a `WHERE` condition without the (+). What that will do (the reason you got no rows) is that all the joins are computed, and only AFTER THAT the WHERE condition is applied. And now the WHERE condition really needs that specific hard-coded value, so it (or the other one on `t3`) will reject all the rows from the outer join. DCookie's solution avoids that.

Comment: Thanks, @mathguy I understood that now and your explanation helps.

Answer (score 2):

Without sample data it is hard to be sure but I think the where clause is to blame.

Including fields from t2 and t3 in the where clause negates the effect of the outer join, unless you also allow nulls (`t2.MSG_TYPE_CD = 13070 OR 2.MSG_TYPE_CD IS NULL`).  Moving those filters into the join allows non-matching records into the results.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    STG_REV_APPORTION_CSC_NO t1
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN STG_SEP_VL t3      ON  t3.BUSINESS_DATE    = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
                                            AND t3.CSC_APP_NO       = t1.CSC_APP_NO
                                            AND t3.JOURNEY_NO       = t1.JOURNEY_NO
                                            AND t3.PURSE_TXN_CTR    = t1.PURSE_TXN_CTR
                                            AND t3.MSG_TYPE_CD      = 4357
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN STG_SEP_VL t2      ON  t2.BUSINESS_DATE    = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
                                            AND t2.CSC_APP_NO       = t1.CSC_APP_NO
                                            AND t2.JOURNEY_NO       = t1.JOURNEY_NO 
                                            AND (t2.TRIP_NO + 1)    = t1.TRIP_NO
                                            AND t2.MSG_TYPE_CD      = 13070 
;
```

I'm not 100% convinced this query is correct.  I *suspect* the right outer joins should be replaced with left outer joins.  That would return every record from t1 and only those from t2 and t3 that match.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to find the exact reason for this mismatch but I think you have interchanged the joining condition for the column PURSE_TXN_CTR in table STG_SEP_VL.

```
SELECT *
FROM STG_REV_APPORTION_CSC_NO t1
RIGHT
JOIN STG_SEP_VL t2
ON  t2.BUSINESS_DATE = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
AND t2.CSC_APP_NO    = t1.CSC_APP_NO
AND t2.JOURNEY_NO    = t1.JOURNEY_NO
AND  ( t2.TRIP_NO + 1 ) = t1.TRIP_NO
RIGHT
JOIN  STG_SEP_VL t3
ON  t3.BUSINESS_DATE    = t1.BUSINESS_DATE
AND t3.CSC_APP_NO     = t1.CSC_APP_NO
AND t3.JOURNEY_NO     = t1.JOURNEY_NO
AND t3.PURSE_TXN_CTR  = t1.PURSE_TXN_CTR
WHERE ( t2.MSG_TYPE_CD  = 13070 AND t3.MSG_TYPE_CD = 4357 );
```