# issue in converting oracle join query to ansi syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, ansi-sql

I am trying to convert the below mentioned query to ansi format

oracle query :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 a,
  table_2 b,
  table_2 c
WHERE c.dt(+)       = a.dt
AND c.ap_no(+)        = a.ap_no
AND c.jy_no(+)        = a.jy_no
AND c.tn(+)           = a.tn
AND b.dt(+)         = a.dt
AND b.ap_no(+)        = a.ap_no
AND b.jy_no(+)        = a.jy_no
AND ( b.t_no(+) + 1 ) = a.t_no  --> unable to understand this part
AND ( b.type_cd(+)       = 100
AND c.type_cd(+)         =  200);
```

ansi format :

```
select * from 
table2 c right outer join table1 a on
c.dt = a.dt
and c.ap_no = a.ap_no
and c.jy_no = a.jy_no
and c.tn = a.tn
left outer join table2 b on
a.dt = b.dt
and a.ap_no = b.ap_no
and a.jy_no = b.jy_no
and a.t_no = b.t_no  ------------------> wrongly implemented it
where b.type_cd = 100 and c.type_cd = 200;
```

I am not understanding, how to convert the +1 found in the "unable to understand this part" of the Oracle query to the ansi format. Please advise.

Edit : this is not fully similar to the problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379864/oracle-plus-joins-to-ansi-conversion) . I am just trying to understand the +1 part of the query.

Comment: Are you taking an exam right now, where you must explain what is wrong with the transformed query? This is highly suspicious - someone else posted a very similar question just a few hours ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle Plus (+) Joins to ANSI conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379864/oracle-plus-joins-to-ansi-conversion)

Comment: @mathguy Yes I have seen that question and I also know the guy who posted that question, I am just trying to understand the +1 part of it

Comment: Keep the +1 after b.t_no, all you need to remove is the (+) but not the +1. If you saw the answer to the other question - there should be no WHERE clause in the transformed query, all the conditions must be in the ON clauses.

Comment: @Mrk Also please note that the (+) notation is *very* deprecated and only exists for backwards compatibility. No one should be writing SQL with that syntax anymore.